# WPF MediaElement stops playing if moved to other screen

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement, multiscreen

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with MediaElement that seems to be related to multi screen environment: occasionally (I can't replicate the problem each time) MediaElement stops playing when I drag the window it's in from a screen to other.
This strange behaivor happens also with a very basic code like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    media.Play();
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
}
```

and

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
                      Name="media" 
                      Source="C:\Users\Maurizio\Desktop\Pulp Fiction.avi"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Has anyone experienced (and eventually solved) any similar problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found a workaround, disabling hardware acceleration in window rendering seems to solve the issue:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;
...

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        HwndTarget hwndTarget = hwndSource.CompositionTarget;
        hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        media.Play();
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    }
```

I can't perceive any difference in performance, and the problem doesn't appear in any test...

Comment: I know this is old, but just wanted to mention that if you position the video so that it is partially across different monitors, video will only play on one side. That's a rather minor issue though.