# MediaElement stops when on hidden tab

Tags: .net, wpf, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement on a Tab in TabControl

When the Tab is changed, the MediaElement stops playing and restarts when the original Tab is reselected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646543/wpf-mediaelement-stops-playing-if-moved-to-other-screen/10656137#10656137 did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set `UnloadedBehavior="Manual"` for the `MediaElement`

Thanks to this answer - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a311a5f5-1138-40a6-8c09-50f19737d81e/mediaelement-unplayable-after-getting-hidden?forum=wpf